# Will react automatically remove eventlisteners when a component unmounts?

Tags: reactjs

Will react automatically remove eventlisteners when a component unmounts, or do I have to remove them in `componentWillUnmount()` ?

I specifically mean event listeners registered to rendered contents of the actual component.

Is it bad practice not to remove them manually?

Example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.content.addEventListener('click', () => alert('Hello'));
  }

  setRef = ref => {
    this.content = ref;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.setRef}>
        <p>Hello World</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Just wonder why don't you simply use `onClick`?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Restuta/e400a555ba24daa396cc But why would you do it like this

Comment: @Yury Tarabanko to illustrate my question and the context, that I mean event listeners bound to the contents of my component...

Comment: you can check like this: https://jsfiddle.net/buxLoovu/

Comment: @NishchalGautam Binding to `document.body` events is not the same. Because it binds to something global relative to the component itself that is not GCed.

Comment: forgot to update my fork, I did do a document.getElementById("container"), but even if we do a addEventListener ourselves, react doesn't have any way to know what we did (I don't think react monkeypatches window), I always use onClick react internally does create event handlers

Answer (score 4):

When the component unmounts, the `<div>` element is removed from the DOM. If the element is removed from the DOM, all its event listeners are removed too.

Comment: @Chris I just checked, there is actually no warning and it works as expected.

Comment: Not sure what applies with refs. But notmally you cannot do this. How did you test unmounting your component?

Comment: @Chris I stopped rendering it.

Comment: Could you post a fiddle or something? This can't be right :/

Answer (score 1):

> Will react automatically remove eventlisteners when a component unmounts?

No, it does not.

> Will I have to remove them in `componentWillUnmount()`?

Yes, that's the right way to do it. Otherwise you may get errors. Here is an example of the error you'll get if you call `setState()` inside the callback of an event that wasn't properly removed on component unmount:

```
Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the undefined component.
```

---

Here's how to solve that:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.content.addEventListener('click', this.myFunc);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.content.removeEventListener('click', this.myFunc);
}

myFunc = () => {
  alert('Hello')
}
```

Comment: Won't GC do this for you?

Comment: But OP doesn't have **global** event listener. Are you sure this logic still applies?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I think there is a bit of a confusion between what *React* does and what the GC will do. As the question reads, React **does not** remove manually added eventListeners, regardless if they are attached to the window object or to a "local" DOM element. React only manages events in its internal event system (e.g events passed as props/attributes such as `onClick`, etc). Also, you shouldn't rely on GC to do the work for you. It is possible to have a situation where an element is removed from the DOM, but a previously attached event still exists. (sorry for the super late answer)

Comment: what about if I want to remove an element that has an event attached to it? if the event is passed as props/attributes like "onClick" or "onChange", then I don't need to remove the event, I can just remove the element itself but if the event is manually added(addEventListener('click',()=>{});) then I'll have to remove the event first, then element itself?? am I correct?

Comment: @It'sTimeToSleep, you are correct about the props. If you added the event listener manually then it depends where you attached it. If you attached it to an element _up_ the DOM tree (such as `document` or `window`) then you have to remove it manually. However, if you added it on the element itself then it will be removed automatically by the browser's GC when the element is removed by React.

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove the event listener using the `componentWillUnmount` method otherwise, you might have memory leaks which might cause your browser to crash or be unresponsive.

The recommended way to handle click events would be as below;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {

  handleClick() {
    alert('Alert!');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
        <p>Hello World</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: "You have to remove the event listener using the componentWillUnmount method otherwise, you might have memory leaks" care to provide a proof.

Comment: And plz pay attention to where OP adds event listner. It is NOT `document.body` or `window` it is an element within the DOM controlled by the component itself that will be garbage collected.

Comment: This video is more of a redux/react video but I think you will get an idea of what I mean. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fgd2ivSnXXo

Comment: I do understand what you mean. This video has nothing to do with the OP's question. Store is **external** object that is **not** garbage collected when component is removed.

Comment: It has nothing to do with OP's question and I mentioned it in the comment but it demonstrates how you can have memory leaks if you have garbage that is not cleaned. And I didn't say OP's particular question/code with have memory leaks, I said in some cases you might have memory leaks in some instances hence I suggested the recommended way to handle click events, no need to add an event listener to do that.

Comment: as i stated several times: it is NOT about the click event. It is about manually adding event listeners on a component's content

Comment: @ManuSchiller still applies mate....just make sure the events are camelCased https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html and this way you don't have to worry about removing them on componentWillUnmount

Comment: does not apply for custom events, so still a valid question